# SQLAlchemy: filtering on value of dict stored in JSONB array field

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My Postgres table has a field called data whose type is JSONB. The format is an array, for example:

```
entity.data = [{"a": 1, "b": "name"}, {"a": 2, "b": "name1"}]
```

I need to find a record having in this array b == "name1".

I'm trying to use this filter but it doesn't work (I think it's because it's for dictionary, not for an array):

```
record = TableName.query.filter(TableName.data['b'].astext == 'name1').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

After multiple trials, finally found the solution:

```
record = TableName.query.filter(TableName.data.contains([{'b': 'name1'}])).first()
```